# docker as slave for jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins2

I have installed Jenkins and docker on the same machine Ubuntu.

- Ubuntu 17.10
- Jenkins ver. 2.73.3
- Docker version 17.09.0-ce.

I am trying to set up jenkins docker containers as slaves for running my automation test suite.

I was able to correctly setup the docker plugin in Jenkins for spinning up docker containers and added a docker template with a image that I created for setting up docker environment.

The image has been built on docker hosted in Ubuntu.

Problem is now when I run a job from Jenkins. It gives an error message:

> (pending—Jenkins doesn’t have label docker-slave)

[image: Jenkins pending image]

When I check the Jenkins logs in Ubuntu machine I see the following error message:

```
> com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.NotFoundException: {"message":"pull access 
denied, "message":may require 'docker login'"}
```

In the ubuntu machine, I have already given done docker login.

The image that I am trying to build containers from is locally on ubuntu, not pushed to any repository, so why is trying to pull the image?

Also, what is the permission issue that I need to resolve? When build a job from jenkins, it's the jenkins user building the container. Do I need to add something else there?

Comment: Also having this issue. Not sure what it could be as I've tried auth with JNLP, SSH injection, SSH with the key directly pasted in, still geting the error with the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the docker image you are using doesn't have the correct name, or is stored in a private repository which requires login.

Please post more information

Comment: thank you @adam yes that was the issue the credential I was giving incorrect credential from jenkins for docker.